# Grouping by year in pivot vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a pivot table in vba with a field that groups dates by month/year; the Date field runs successfully, but when I add the code to group it by month/year, it gives me an "object required error". How should I fix this?

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("APivotTable").PivotFields("Date")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
'Error is here
.LabelRange.Group Start:=True, End:=True, _
Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, True)
.Position = 1
End With
```

Comment: You're missing a dot in front of `LabelRange`.

Comment: sorry, that was actually a c/p mistake lol, but I got the solution below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this after `End with` line.

```
'Change Range("A5") as per your requirement
Range("A5").Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
    False, True, False, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself and was looking for a solution.  While Maddy's answer is correct, I really dislike the idea of using a hard coded range instead of the OP's approach of using names.

OP's approach was almost correct. Some additional sleuthing led me to realize the issue is that the Group method must be used on the *data* of the field you are trying to group, and the OP was using the method on the *label* of the field.

The solution is very easy.  Just move the range being grouped by one cell - from the label to the data using `Cells`:

```
.LabelRange.Cells(2,1).Group Start:=True, End:=True, _
Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, True)
```